# Get a div to with background to stretch to the bottom of the parent div

Tags: html, css

I have two divs inside another div--one with a background color, the other with just white.

I keep trying to figure out out to be able to get both of them to stretch to the bottom of the outer div, depending on whichever on is longest, without leaving a white space on the left div or cutting off the background or content on one of them. I always end up cutting off the left div.

In the project both divs are dynamic and can be anywhere from empty to really long. I would like to show a solid color to the bottom of the page on the left side when the menu is longer than the content on the right. Likewise, when the content is shorter then the menu, I don't want have anything cut off.

I have created a jsfiddle example of my problem that I'm having: 
http://jsfiddle.net/nKATZ/

It looks right if the menu is shorter then the body: http://jsfiddle.net/nKATZ/1/

Here is the code:

**html**

```
<div class="mainBox">
<div class="leftBox">
    <a href="#">here</a><br />
    <a>here</a><br />
    <a>here</a><br /><a>here</a><br />
    <a>here</a><br />
    <a>here</a><br />
    <a>here</a><br />
    <a>here</a><br />
    <a>here</a><br />
    <a>here</a><br />
</div>
<div class="rightBox">
    body textbody text<br />
    body textbody text<br />
    body textbody text<br />
    body textbody text<br />
    body textbody text<br />
    body textbody text<br />
    body textbody text<br />
    body textbody text<br />
    body textbody text<br />
    body textbody text<br />
    body textbody text<br />
    body textbody text<br />
    body textbody text<br />
    body textbody text<br />
    body textbody text<br />
</div>
<div class="clear" ></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
body {
    background: #15384C;
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
}
.mainBox {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 960px; 
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: vissable;
}
.leftBox {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #CF4A41;
}
.rightBox {
    width:720px; 
    float: right;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: So you're wanting the white part to go all the way to the bottom of the physical window, regardless of content, right?

Comment: What I am trying to do is get the left side of the page to ways fill the vertical space (the part in red) http://jsfiddle.net/nKATZ/2/ but to not get cut off http://jsfiddle.net/sqpMa/ (see the text at the bottom left) While also not having any white area under the red box http://jsfiddle.net/nKATZ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
body {
    background: #15384C;
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
}
.mainBox {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 960px; 
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;

}
.leftBox {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #CF4A41;
    margin-bottom: -2000px;
    padding-bottom: 2000px; 
}
.rightBox {
    width:720px; 
    float: right;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: sorry still doesn't solve the problem just makes the main box go to the bottom of the page. http://jsfiddle.net/HcXDc/

Comment: @Justin Now that I think I understand you better, I changed the solution.  Does this do what you want?  The main change is that the left box position should be relative.

Comment: see when i test this in fiddle it works perfectly other then when the menu is shorter then the content then it still shows the white space under the left box (the box in red doesn't extend to the bottom of the mainBox) but if the menu is longer it's working right.(example of it not going to the bottom) http://jsfiddle.net/qYwQF/1/ Thanks for your help UtapiaLtd would more photos of what im going for help? Or anything i can do to try and explain better? Sorry I'm not able to explain better.

Comment: Here is a example of what I'm trying to do and it does everything i want it just uses jquery to get it to work it feels like to me that there should be a way to do this with out javascript. Both the left and right side can be shorter then the other with out damaging the look of the page http://jsfiddle.net/NeKsZ/1/

Comment: Oh, so you DO want the red to go all the way down.  Gotcha.  I've updated this once more.

Comment: Be warned that this uses evil negative and positive margin and padding sorcery, but I think it does what you're asking while avoiding any scripting! :-)  If you wind up with particularly long content, you need to adjust those padding and margin values.

Comment: If you don't like doing it this way, the other solution is just to make a background image about a pixel or two tall with the colors for the columns split where you like them and then just set that as the background for .mainBox

Comment: Yes! Your evil sorcery worked! That is exactly what i wanted to do!

Comment: I should have thought about the background that's a good idea, too. Thanks so much UtopiaLtd!

Answer (score 1):

I think these 2 lines will solve your problem.

```
.leftBox {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #CF4A41;
    height: 100%; /* add this line */
    position: absolute;  /* and this line */
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nKATZ/2/)

Comment: But this doesn't fix the problem with menu (red box) having more content then the right side http://jsfiddle.net/qKG2q/